# Several same node name to a list of string

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I have an XML file.

I tried this query. But I like when I'd like a List with the value "AAA" and "BBB" when I get the node "Val1"

An idea ?

```
var res = doc.Descendants("Tags")
.Where(p => p.Elements("code")
.Any(c => (string)c.Parent.Attribute("id") == "Val1"))
.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray().First();

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MyTag>
  <Tags id="Val1">
    <code>AAA</code>
    <code>BBB</code>
  </Tags>
  <Tags id="Val2">
    <code>CCC</code>
    <code>DDD</code>
    <code>EEE</code>
  </Tags> 
</MyTag>
```

Comment: `doc.Root.Elements("Tags").Single(t => (string)t.Attribute("id") == "Val1").Elements("code").Select(c => c.Value)`

Answer (score 0):

You either need :

```
var res = doc.Descendants("Tags")
.Where(p => p.Elements("code")
.Any(c => (string)c.Parent.Attribute("id") == "Val1"))
.Select(i => i.Elements("code")).ToArray().First();
```

or this:

```
var res = doc.Descendants("Tags")
.Where(p => p.Elements("code")
.Any(c => (string)c.Parent.Attribute("id") == "Val1"))
.Select(i => i.Elements("code").Select (x => (string)x.Value)).ToArray().First();
```

The first will get you a array of elements like `<code>AAAA</code>` while the second will get you an array of strings like `AAAA`

Comment: The `.ToArray()` has no function.